# How to aggregate elements based on a value they share Java

Tags: java, list

I have list of Entities which share equal Group number if they belong to the same group

| Start | Stop | GroupNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ***2018-11-13*** | 2019-01-13 | 1 |
| 2019-01-14 | 2019-03-06 | 1 |
| 2019-03-07 | ***2019-11-18*** | 1 |
| ***2020-08-23*** | 2020-08-23 | 2 |
| 2021-11-19 | ***2022-12-23*** | 2 |

These Entities are saved in an ArrayList

```
List<Entities> baseList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static class Entities {
        private final Date start_dt;
        private final Date stop_dt;
        private int groupNum;
```

I want to aggregate objects based on the GroupNum, and take the first **Start** date from the first element of the (this).group and the last **stop** date from the same group.

Final result should look something like this:

| Start | Stop | GroupNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ***2018-11-13*** | ***2019-11-18*** | 1 |
| ***2020-08-23*** | ***2022-12-23*** | 2 |

I wanted to share my solution, however I couldn't come up with any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not quite sure what problem you're facing, could you provide some code on what the objects containing that data look like? If they are mutable you could just maintain a map with group number being the key and the aggregate being the value. Then just "merge" each corresponding element into the aggregate by applying necessary rules (e.g. update start date only if it's before the aggregate's and end date only if it's after).

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I just updated the question, and yes they are mutable, they are saved in an arrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to aggregate `Entities` as follows:

- `groupNum` will be the grouping criteria
- earliest `start_dt` and latest `stop_dt` should be used.

As I already suggested in my comment, try to use a `Map<Integer, Entities>` where the key is the group number:

```
Map<Integer, Entities> aggregates = new HashMap<>();

for( Entities entry : baseList ) {
  //get the aggregate or create it if none exists for this group
  Entities aggregate = aggregates.computeIfAbsent(entry.getGroupNum(), 
     k -> new Entities(entry.getStart_Dt(), entry.getStop_Dt(), entry.getGroupNum());

  //compare and update the dates as needed
  if( aggregate.getStart_Dt().compareTo(entry.getStart_Dt()) > 0) {
    aggregate.setStart_Dt(entry.getStart_Dt());
  }

  if( aggregate.getStop_Dt().compareTo(entry.getStop_Dt()) < 0) {
    aggregate.setStart_Dt(entry.getStop_Dt());
  }
}
```

A few notes:

- This approach doesn't require the list to be sorted and doesn't maintain any order. If order by group number should be maintained either use a `TreeMap` to sort by group number or a `LinkedHashMap` to keep the order of the list (as much as applicable - you're merging list elements after all)
- If you'd use the `java.time`, e.g. `LocalDate` instead of `java.util.Date` you could use the easier to read methods `isBefore()` and `isAfter()`.
- If you don't want to check the dates on a newly created aggregate use the following snippet as the loop body:

  ```
  Entities aggregate = aggregates.get(entry.getGroupNum());
  if( aggregate == null ) {
    aggregates.put( entry.getGroupNum(), new Entities(entry.getStart_Dt(), entry.getStop_Dt(), entry.getGroupNum());
  } else {
    if( aggregate.getStart_Dt().compareTo(entry.getStart_Dt()) > 0) {
      aggregate.setStart_Dt(entry.getStart_Dt());
    }

    if( aggregate.getStop_Dt().compareTo(entry.getStop_Dt()) < 0) {
      aggregate.setStart_Dt(entry.getStop_Dt());
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    List<Entities> baseList = List.of(
        new Entities("2018-11-13", "2019-01-13", 1),
        new Entities("2019-01-14", "2019-03-06", 1),
        new Entities("2019-03-07", "2019-11-18", 1),
        new Entities("2020-08-23", "2020-08-23", 2),
        new Entities("2021-11-19", "2022-12-23", 2));
    List<Entities> result = baseList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entities::getGroupNum))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new Entities(
            e.getValue().get(0).getStart_dt(),
            e.getValue().get(e.getValue().size() - 1).getStop_dt(),
            e.getKey()))
        .toList();
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

output:

```
Entities [start_dt=2018-11-13, stop_dt=2019-11-18, groupNum=1]
Entities [start_dt=2020-08-23, stop_dt=2022-12-23, groupNum=2]
```